# Javascript + RegEx: Inconsistent Switch case performance

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a noob and need some assistance. I am working on a personal project: a text based game. I created a switch case to parse the user input. All but one of the cases works consistently. The case in question can be found here:

https://github.com/cornopaez/cornopaez.github.io/blob/dev/js/adventure-game/controller/controller.js#L386

For those who don't want to hit the link, the code looks like this (without all the extra logic):

```
var solve = /^solve mystery$/g;

switch (user_input) {
  //Some cases

  case (solve.test(input_string) ? input_string : ""):
    //game logic
    break;

  //Other cases including Default
}
```

In short, copy/paste "solve mystery" and calling the parser results in mixed results. The logic inside the case only runs every other time. All other cases with a similar setup (a var for the RegEx and a case with the ternary setup) work consistently, without any issues.

As I'm a noob, I know there's probably a better way to achieve the same results in a more succinct way.

Any ideas how to fix this bothersome bug?

Comment: How do you know it only runs every other time? Did you put a `console.log` in there, or…?

Comment: @Ryan The internal case logic adds some specific HTML on the game UI as feed back for the user. In this case, it runs correctly every other time, the other times the logic got the the default case (which adds some different HTML).

Comment: You may use if/else instead of switch here

Comment: As you say it's "a text based game" so you don't have to worry about that little of performance loose